# Importing modules in python taking longer than expected

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

So I have a process in which a script (call it A) pulls in data (by importing and running a function within another script B) and runs calculations on the data. After all calculations are performed, A then runs checks (by importing and running a function within another script C).

There is another script (D) which contains various small sized functions and dictionaries, used across the two scripts B and C.

I have placed timestamps in between each step made by Script A. 
This has revealed that when the script comes to import B the time taken just to import varies between 30-40 minutes! There is nothing in script B that is outside a function, other than the line "from D import *".

In D, the only code outside of defs are list and dictionary definitions.

When the script is on a loop for different groups of data, this delay only occurs in the first instance.

Also, when I run the check script C on it's own it only takes 2 minutes to run.

My gut tells me it has something to do with the import of D into both scripts (this is imported by the code "from D import *" in both scripts. But I don't know why/how this can be improved?

Thanks

Comment: put the work of your module into a main function and put `if __name__ == '__main__': exit(main())` at the end of your file

Comment: B and C are already in functions. I'll edit the post to make this clear.